# Flight availability

Tags: air-travel, bermuda

I am looking at flight WS2711 from Bermuda to Toronto with Westjet on December 18, 2016 but it say there is only two seats available. Does that mean the flight is full? How can I find more information on the number of seats available on a specific flight?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because information on availability of seats on a specific flight will go out of date almost instantly and will be of no interest to anybody after the flight leaves in a few days' time.

Comment: I rewrote the question to be a bit more general.

Comment: Most likely, all that means is there's 2 seats left at the price displayed.  There very well could be many more open seats.  There are sites such as Expert Flyer that show different fare class availability, but that still doesn't always translate into total availability.

Comment: @Relaxed you could have dropped "general." in your comment - and it would have rocked!

Answer (score 8):

The availability at time of writing for that flight is `Y7 V5 B2 Q0 L0 M0 P0 G0 X0 D0 I0 C0 K7 W0 H0` (as seen from a sales office in the United States).

Therefore, the "only two seats available" probably refers to the two remaining seats in the `B` bucket. Purchasing seats out of the `V` or `Y` inventory is likely to be more expensive. With `Y7` there are probably five further seats for sale after `B` is sold out, and perhaps more. However that is not necessarily so.

With at least seven seats for sale it is unlikely the flight is full, but then again I do not know how far WS would be willing to oversell the flight.

Comment: (+1) The explanation is useful but could you also indicate (broadly) how you obtained this information? It is somehow available publicly on the Internet?

Comment: @Relaxed I have a subscription to ExpertFlyer.com, which is fed by Galileo.

Comment: @pnuts Depends on the GDS favoured by the airline. Amadeus goes up to 9, Sabre only goes up to 7.

Comment: @pnuts Oh yes, the availability can certainly differ by codeshare. Availability can also differ by sales office location, so a flight can (theoretically) look full to an agent in Christchurch but empty to an agent in London.

Comment: 7, or 9, since that's a single digit.  7 is common since there is/was a quasi limit of 6 passengers on a PNR.

Comment: @Johns-305, for the non-travel agents among us, what's a "PNR"?

Comment: @FreeMan Passenger Name Record. The de facto name, and frequently format, of an itinerary.